# how to count number of rows using condition on 2 lines

Tags: php, mysql

I try to make a request on 2 line.
I have an php code to make a planning. I record the disponibility of my personnel on a table like this :

[image]

It's easy to

```
select count(*) from table where idPerso = x and h06==1 and h07==1 ...
```

But i don't know to

```
count(*) from table where h23==1 and h00==1 next day ...
```

any idea ?

thanks a lot

Comment: What's your question about?.. to get count for the next day?

Answer (score 0):

```
count(*) from ... where ... and `Date` = DATE_ADD(`Date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

That should do the trick.

See the MySQL Manual at "Date & Time Functions" for more details ---> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add